# is there a library for xamarin for platform specific features?

Tags: xamarin

I'm developing a cross platform (ios/android/wp) app that needs to do basic things like dialing a number, sending a message, sending an email, reading/writing events in the calendar, taking a picture, etc. All those things have different APIs on the different platforms. Is there a library that abstracts those things and implements them on each platform in the platform's native way?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these components:

[Xamarin.Mobile](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.mobile)
[Xamarin.Auth](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.auth)
[Xamarin.Social](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social)

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at this project which is intended for use from within Xamarin.Forms projects:

[Xamarin.Forms.Labs](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs)

Whilst this project includes a lot of GUI controls intended for Xamarin.Forms apps, it does include abstractions for platform specific services such as:

- Accelerometer
- Cache
- Camera (Picture and Video picker, Take Picture, Take Video)
- Device (battery info, device info, sensors, accelerometers)
- Display
- Geolocator
- Phone Service (cellular network info, make phonecalls)
- SoundService
- Text To Speech

Which you could make use of to abstract out your phone calling / taking photo concerns as needed.